# Setting a shapes path transition to another shapes rotation in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, shapes, transition

I have created a circle with a triangle in front of it that moves forward and backward with the circle. What I want now is to make the triangle orbit the circle as the circle rotates. My first thought is that this will require PathTransition and binding but, thus far I have had no luck. Here is my code:

```
public class FXTest2 extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane pane = new Pane();


    Ellipse ell = new Ellipse();
    ell.setCenterX(850);
    ell.setCenterY(500);
    ell.setRadiusX(480);
    ell.setRadiusY(480);
    ell.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    ell.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

    Circle circ1 = new Circle(500.0f, 500.0f, 25.0f);
    circ1.setFill(Color.GREEN);

    Path path = new Path();

    Polygon tri1 = new Polygon(530, 495, 530, 505, 540, 500);
    tri1.translateXProperty().bind(circ1.translateXProperty());
    tri1.translateYProperty().bind(circ1.translateYProperty());
    PathTransition pathMove = new PathTransition();
    pathMove.setNode(tri1);
    pathMove.setPath(circ1.getRotate());

    circ1.setOnKeyPressed((e) -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            circ1.setTranslateX(circ1.getTranslateX() - 15);
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
            circ1.setRotate(circ1.getRotate() - 15);
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            circ1.setRotate(circ1.getRotate() + 15);
        }
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            circ1.setTranslateX(circ1.getTranslateX() + 15);
        }

    });

    pane.getChildren().addAll(ell, circ1, tri1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 1700, 1000); 
    scene.getStylesheets().add("NewFile.css");

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("FXTest2");
    primaryStage.show();

    circ1.requestFocus();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rotate the triangle around the center of the circle. To do this, create a `Rotate` transform, bind its pivot point to the center of the circle, and its angle to the amount the circle is rotated. Then just add the rotate transform to the list of the triangle's transforms:

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
rotate.pivotXProperty().bind(circ1.centerXProperty());
rotate.pivotYProperty().bind(circ1.centerYProperty());
rotate.angleProperty().bind(circ1.rotateProperty());

tri1.getTransforms().add(rotate);
```